# Wget not getting cookies, not pulling back results in check.

Tags: linux, bash, wget, tcp, nagios

I'm having a couple of issues when porting check scripts between a couple of servers.

The script.

```
#!/bin/bash

hostname=$1
port=$2
retstatus=0
retStr=
st=`date "+%s.%N"`

if [ $# -ne 2 ]; then
  echo "Error, invalid parameters passed"
  exit 3
fi

tmp_cook=`mktemp`
wget --no-check-certificate --keep-session-cookies --save-cookies $tmp_cook https://$hostname:$port/LoginForm.jsp -O /dev/null -o /dev/null

ta=`date "+%s.%N"`
wget --no-check-certificate --load-cookies $tmp_cook --keep-session-cookies --save-cookies $tmp_cook --post-data="j_username=scott&j_password=tiger" https://$hostname:$port/j_security_check -O /dev/null -o /dev/null

tb=`date "+%s.%N"`
ok2=`wget --no-check-certificate --load-cookies $tmp_cook --keep-session-cookies --save-cookies $tmp_cook https://$hostname:$port/MainMenu.jsp -o /dev/null -O - | grep 'Customer Care' | wc -l`
if [ $ok2 -gt 0 ]; then
  retStr="SITE OK."
else
  retStatus=2
  retStr="SITE NOT OK."
fi

#echo 'Got session:'
rm -f $tmp_cook
et=`date "+%s.%N"`
da=`echo "$ta - $st" | bc`
db=`echo "$tb - $st" | bc`
dz=`echo "$et - $st" | bc`


printf "%s|SITE LOGIN:%02.2f,%02.2f,%02.2f\n" "$retStr" $da $db $dz
exit $retStatus
```

when I run it in debug mode :

```
[nagios@mr-slave libexec]$ bash -x check_Login.sh node001.company.com 16004
+ hostname=node001.company.com
+ port=16004
+ retstatus=0
+ retStr=
++ date +%s.%N
+ st=1427736385.648488303
+ '[' 2 -ne 2 ']'
++ mktemp
+ tmp_cook=/tmp/tmp.ye9MyQfgJp
+ wget --no-check-certificate --keep-session-cookies --save-cookies /tmp/tmp.ye9MyQfgJp https://node001.company.com:16004/LoginForm.jsp -O /dev/null -o /dev/null
++ date +%s.%N
+ ta=1427736385.676642983
+ wget --no-check-certificate --load-cookies /tmp/tmp.ye9MyQfgJp --keep-session-cookies --save-cookies /tmp/tmp.ye9MyQfgJp '--post-data=j_username=scott&j_password=tiger' https://node001.company.com:16004/j_security_check -O /dev/null -o /dev/null
++ date +%s.%N
+ tb=1427736385.702942948
++ wget --no-check-certificate --load-cookies /tmp/tmp.ye9MyQfgJp --keep-session-cookies --save-cookies /tmp/tmp.ye9MyQfgJp https://node001.company.com:16004/MainMenu.jsp -o /dev/null -O -
++ grep 'menu 1'
++ wc -l
+ ok2=0
+ '[' 0 -gt 0 ']'
+ retStatus=2
+ retStr='SITE NOT OK.'
++ date +%s.%N
+ et=1427736385.729800960
++ echo '1427736385.676642983 - 1427736385.648488303'
++ bc
+ da=.028154680
++ bc
++ echo '1427736385.702942948 - 1427736385.648488303'
+ db=.054454645
++ echo '1427736385.729800960 - 1427736385.648488303'
++ bc
+ dz=.081312657
+ printf '%s|SITE LOGIN:%02.2f,%02.2f,%02.2f\n' 'SITE NOT OK.' .028154680 .054454645 .081312657
SITE NOT OK.|SITE LOGIN:0.03,0.05,0.08
+ exit 2
```

So then I checked the cookie content in the tmp file.

```
[nagios@dub-company-slave libexec]$ cat /tmp/tmp.ye9MyQfgJp
# HTTP cookie file.
# Generated by Wget on 2015-03-30 18:26:25.
# Edit at your own risk.
```

No Information in here, I would expect something more like the following:

```
nagios@dub-company-slave [libexec] -->> cat /tmp/tmp.wdOvUJ9695
# HTTP cookie file.
# Generated by Wget on 2015-03-30 18:19:11.
# Edit at your own risk.

node001.company.com:16004   FALSE   /       FALSE   0       JSESSIONID      RMw8VZFPvnnDFcmLzThjgp2mMDJ1GLgt4w8XJpRn1BWn2QNQrQjP!250469950
node001.company.com:16004   FALSE   /       TRUE    0       _wl_authcookie_ 6QxOZhTJCc9JyyL2lrZZ
```

This script works from a different slave, and the only apparent difference I can see is two marginally different versions of wget.

GNU Wget 1.11.4 Red Hat modified, which works / GNU Wget 1.12 built on linux-gnu which doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

With the new version of Wget, it's default encryption type was SSL3 rather than TLS1.0, which is what the site uses.

--secure-protocol=TLSv1 made everything work just fine :)